# Tool for .NET like Yahoo Pipes

Tags: c#, yahoo-pipes

I'm developing an application that uses Yahoo Pipes to get information.

The main problem is that Yahoo Pipes has 200 per 10 minutes limitation and it could be a limitation to my app.

I'm wondering if exists any framework to .Net with the same GUI, and tools

Thanks =)

Comment: Yahoo Pipes is a web service. You can talk to it from any language. So the Yahoo Pipes equivalent for C# is... Yahoo Pipes.

Comment: Great information you gave me... lol. I'm asking if exists any tool or framework like Yahoo Pipes for .Net ;)

Answer (score 0):

BizTalk is nasty to work with and overly enterprisey for my liking, but it does have some similar functionality with a GUI for setting things up.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.popfly.ms/ just try ..whether it works ..i guess its been closed

Answer (score 0):

Yahoo Pipes can export a JSON definition of the blocks used to construct a particular pipe, and how they are wired together.... which means it's possible to user Yahoo Pipes as a visual design environment and export the JSON definition of a pipe, then compile it and run it elsewhere.

I don't know if there is a .NET implementation, but there is a Python compiler, [pipe2py](https://github.com/ggaughan/pipe2py), that will create a Python equivalent of a Yahoo pipe and allow you to run it elsewhere. See also [Exporting Yahoo Pipe Definitions, Compiling Them to Python, and Running Them in Scraperwiki](http://blog.ouseful.info/2012/04/10/exporting-yahoo-pipe-definitions-compiling-them-to-python-and-running-them-in-scraperwiki/), which describes how to compile Python equivalents of Yahoo Pipes in Scraperwiki.